# Extracting elements of an array

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am having a bit of trouble accessing the individual elements for example 'fullName' in the array.

```
[
    {
        pk: "pk1",
        sk: "sk1",
        entity: "entity1",
        id: "id1",
        companyId: "companyId",
        country: "country",
        location: "location",
        title: "title1",
        description: "Description1",
        startDate: "2021-02-19T11:44:08.079Z",
        endDate: "2022-01-05T11:44:08.079Z",
        type: 10,
        participationType: 1,
        participants: [
            {
                mapOfPoints: [],
                fullName: "Full Name1",
                userId: "user-id-1",
                dateJoined: "2020-05-25T15:22:45.941Z",
                points: 10
            }
        ],
        prizes: [
            {
                conditionValue: "1st",
                conditionType: "RANKING",
                prizeValue: 100,
                prizeType: "COINS"
            }
        ],
        imageUrl: "ImageURL1"
    }
    ,
    {
        pk: "pk2",
        sk: "sk2",
        entity: "entity2",
        id: "id2",
        companyId: "companyID",
        title: "title2",
        description: "Description2",
        startDate: "2021-04-27T13:39:21.000Z",
        endDate: "2021-04-29T13:39:21.000Z",
        type: 0,
        participationType: 1,
        participants: [
            {
                mapOfPoints: [],
                fullName: "Full Name2",
                userId: "test-user-2",
                dateJoined: "2021-04-26T14:46:55.963Z",
                points: 0
            }
        ],
        prizes: [
            {
                conditionValue: "1st",
                conditionType: "RANKING",
                prizeValue: 100,
                prizeType: "COINS"
            }
        ],
        imageUrl: "ImageURL2"
    }
]
```

I have tried accessing various elements of the array using a for loop but to no avail. Here is an example of the for loop:

```
     for (var i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
       console.log("Element: ",res[i].participants[i])
   }
```

The result I got was that the first one element would print out successfully but the loop would crash on the second iteration.

I would like to be able to access the elements in the array any help is welcome.

Comment: Why should the same index work for two independent arrays? You need a loop for the entities and one loop for the participants of those entities.

Comment: Hi @Andreas they are not separate arrays I dont think. How would you approach this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the same index for both `res` array and the `participants` array. You need to have different indexes:

```
for (var i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < res[i].participants.length; j++) {
    console.log("Element: ",res[i].participants[j])
   }
}
```

or better with Array methods

```
res.forEach((el, i) => {
  console.log('Element: ', i)
  el.participants.forEach(participant => {
    console.log('Participant: ', participant)
  })
})
```

Comment: Oh @boxdox you were faster by moment :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your approach is to use `i` variable as key in both `res` and `participants` arrays. You need something like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {

  for (var z = 0; z < myArray[i].participants.length; z++) {

       console.log("Element: ", myArray[i].participants[z])
   }

 }
```